# How to display a string for DataTime in the localized format as in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, globalization

I use Asp.net 4 and C#.

I have a Table in my DataBase with a DateTime Column formatted like this: `2011-08-11 11:32:50.43`

I need display a string with the DateTime formatted in the right format accordingly to the Web.Config
in my case:

```
<globalization culture="auto:de" uiCulture="de"/>
```

So my question: How to set a string rappresenting DateTime accodingly to `globalization culture`?

Comment: If your DateTime column is actualy storing it as a date, then there is no formatting within, that is just how it is displayed to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo is what you are interested in. There is a hefty [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) for just this, actually. I also wrote a short example for you but I wasn't sure if you meant 08 as the month, or day, but you can easily switch that.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ff", formatInfo));
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess here is what you need :
[DateTime.ToString Method (IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx)

For your case it must look like this :

```
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        DateTime curretnDate = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("Date : {0}", 
                           curretnDate.ToString(culture));
```

Comment: I need get the CultureInfo from the Web.Config setting, so I should I change your script?

Comment: No problem ... just use CurrentCulture or CurrentUICulture, that's it.